# How many Time Lords are there after Time War?

Tags: doctor-who, time-lord, time-war

How many Time Lords are there after Time War?

> It seems that there is The Doctor, The Master, River Song (if count as Time Lord) and Jenny (I don't count Donna) but I am not sure if I haven't missed someone.

**EDIT:**

Of course we know now that

> Gallifrey wasn't *really* destroyed so presumably there are still a lot of them remaining.

Comment: What do you mean by "after" in the context of a race of time-travellers?

Comment: We all know that from a "non-linear, non-subjective viewpoint" (...) [time is like] a big ball of wibbly-wobbly... timey-wimey... stuff". IIRC from subjective POV of Tardis Gallifrey time is sort of linear.

Comment: In this case, "after" will make sense, e.g. ("after the time lock was imposed"). Technically once the time lock was imposed, it had always been imposed from the perspective of humans, but when you're trying to describe 4th-dimensional concepts in a language designed for sharing information regarding soft-fruit locations, you do what you can with what you've got.

Comment: Susan is in the future so she still count as being "alive" and river is dead now technically to the eleventh doctor so she might return with Peter, hopefully they re-introduce Susan.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are only two plus some uncertainty:  The Doctor and the Master, and Jenny is the uncertainty.

River Song has some Time Lord DNA by virtue of being conceived on the TARDIS (IIRC).  She is not a pure Time Lord and as far as we know, only inherited the regeneration ability which she has since forsaken.

Jenny is a question mark.  She is biologically a Time Lord, with two hearts and at least one regeneration.  However the Doctor claims that this is not only what makes a Time Lord:

> You're an echo, that's all. A Time Lord is so much more.  A sum of knowledge, a code, shared history, shared suffering.

In Doctor Who Confidential, she is referred to as

> another member of that race, or something closely akin to it.

The Doctor later accepts her for herself, but it is not established whether that involves accepting her as a Time Lord.

Comment: In the original series, there was a vague, unspecified, but notably present difference between a "Gallifreyan" and a "Time Lord/Lady"; I suspect Jenny is a former but not a latter.

Comment: I believe The Doctor's 'echo statement' about Jenny was out of his own ignorance and personality. Donna seemed to vehemently disagree with his notion that she was not a Time Lord.

Answer (score 4):

There are plenty timelocked with Gallifrey, but we only know for sure of two outside of it. The Doctor and The Master. There is a possibility that Susan, the Doctor's granddaughter and Romana may still be alive, but it's unknown.