# Can there be any more NEW Time Lords?

Tags: doctor-who, time-lord

According to [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/17623/3383), a time lord can only be "created" on Gallifrey:

> The title and distinction belongs solely to those beings from the world of Gallifrey who have been indoctrinated, trained and introduced to the Time Vortex via a particular set of rituals, instruction and guidance

So does that mean that there can be no more new time lords since Gallifrey is in a time lock?

Comment: The only constant in the world of Dr Who is that it's no respecter of its own canon. There's no reason to assume the writers won't decide to introduce a whole bevy of new Timelords, or just one, or none, or a female timelord, or a timelord that's trapped in the body of a dog.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Short Answer:

According to the definition given above (the generally accepted definition of a Time Lord *at this point*), no there can not, for two reasons:

- There cannot be any more being from the world of Gallifrey.
- There is no one left to indoctrinate/instruct/guide them.

(I am making an additional assumption here that the Council of Time Lords must be involved in this indoctrination, and they are obviously not around.)

Longer Answer:

There is nothing to prevent The Doctor from attempting to start a new tradition of Time Lords.

The natives of Gallifrey became Time Lords because of their extremely advanced technology, and the actions of Rassilon and Omega. It's not clear if there is any physical difference between a Time Lord and a non-Time Lord Gallifreyan (e.g. an Outsider). There have been indications that humans, as an example, are anatomically unable to cope with the awareness of time that a Time Lord must have, but that there are ways to overcome this:

- Rose Tyler and Donna Noble both temporarily absorbed the knowledge of the Time Vortex (through different means) but their human brain was unable to cope.
- The Meta-Crisis Doctor was half-human (one heart, not regenerations) but otherwise appears to have the same awareness of time as The Doctor.
- River Song gained some level of Time Lord-ness from her exposure to the TARDIS during gestation, giving her "Time Lord DNA" (I don't know if this means Gallifreyan DNA, which I would find very odd, or if it simply mutated her DNA in such a way to give her Time Lord-like characteristics).

Depending on what exactly makes a Gallifreyan into a Time Lord, it is possible that the same alterations could be made to a human (or other species) to allow them to handle the Time Vortex. If that is the case, it is feasible for The Doctor to start a new generation of Time Lords under his guidance. Otherwise, he would have to get busy procreating :)

Comment: Great reasoning, +1 (One less thing I will try to answer today.)

Comment: Regarding "Timelord DNA" - In _The Two Doctors_, when Chessene is trying to turn Patrick Troughton's doctor into an Andragum (sp?) by genetic transfer she says "_Leave him the power of time travel, leave the symbiotic nuclei within him..._"

Answer (score 4):

New answer for more recent in-canon events:

More recent events in new!Who canon suggest that Gallifrey may return, especially as it is not in a time lock as previously understood but another universe (or possibly a "bubble universe", much like that which the House once occupied...).

As such, it would be possible for there to be new Time Lords.

Even without this, however, there is (as Michael Edenfield pointed out in his answer) no reason the Doctor cannot attempt to start his own tradition of Time Lords, especially if he can find or make a new Untempered Schism (which, while it seems to have been used as a rite of passage for *all* Gallifreyans, is also clearly tied to the Time Lord Academy).  It is clear that species other than Gallifreyans are able to become Time Lords, as the Classic Who companion Ace eventually left the TARDIS to study on Gallifrey, with the eventual aim of doing exactly that, so this is not an obstacle.

It should, however, be noted that if any such new Time Lords were to have their own TARDISes, either the most recent object to referred to as the Eye of Harmony would have to be transplanted to somewhere whence its power could be transmitted across all of space and time (and to turn out to have been the one that used to sit under the Citadel on Gallifrey, which was in just such a setup) or the Doctor would need access to the Hand of Omega with which to create a new one.  Otherwise, while it would be possible to grow new TARDISes from "TARDIS coral", they would have considerable difficulty obtaining power.